# React - why changing state works faster in incognito mode?

Tags: reactjs, zustand

I am using Zustand for state management (without any persistence options). I have a pretty simple store:

```js
export const useStore = create<State>()(
  devtools((set) => ({
    map: null,
    setMap: (map: Map) => set(() => ({ map })),

    layer: null,
    setLayer: (layer: Layer) => set(() => ({ layer })),

    source: null,
    setSource: (source: VectorSource) => set(() => ({ source })),

    userRole: UserRole.EDITOR,
    setUserRole: (role: UserRole) => set(() => ({ userRole: role })),
  }))
);
```

In my app there is a switch which sets user role:

[image]

What I noticed is that in normal mode (even in production settings) changing this one simple variable is really slow.
What is really interesting that **in chrome's incognito mode it works flawlesly without any noticable delay** - just instantly.

What may be causing it? For production mode in normal tab it is ~2 seconds. For production mode in incognito tab it is just instant.

---

Update:
`map` I am holding in store is an OpenLayers map object.
After rewriting it to use context instead of zustand's store it works significantly faster. Still don't know why.

Comment: Any chance you configured your incognito mode on chrome to block some things? It might make things significantly faster depending on what you configured there

Comment: I didn't configure anything